# Do Psi Zombies give experience when their controller is killed?

Tags: xcom-2

According to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/XCOM2/comments/45a9y7/do_psi_zombies_give_xp/) it sounds like Psi Zombies give experience when they are directly killed by taking damage. Do they also grant experience when the zombie dies indirectly, like killing or disorienting the Sectoid which raised them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I have no other source than my experiencee from the game, with countless of tries on legend iron man campaigns.

Psi zombies who die indirectly because their controller dies or gets disoriented will show up in the enemies killed statistic at end of the mission. But they do not contribute to any sodier's kill count, unless the zombie is killed directly. If you really can afford the risk, actions, and time it takes, you should try to kill any zombies before finishing their controllers to maximize experience.

The first mission with legend difficulty for example has 8 enemies, one of which is a sectoid. The soldiers' combined personal kills after succesful mission will be 8. The exceptions are a blowing car killing an enemy which will result in less than 8 personal kills, or killing a zombie before its controller which will result in more than 8 personal kills, e.g. 3+3+2+1 for the four soldiers in the post-mission screen when they show up on the Avenger deck.

*Edit: added further explanation from my comment below as suggested.*

Comment: Thanks for answering! Could you state what your source for this information is?

Comment: I'm afraid the only source is my own experience. I have almost 300 hours of XCOM 2 on the record and I've noticed this several times. The first mission with legend difficulty for example has 8 enemies, one of which is a sectoid. The soldiers' combined personal kills after succesful missions will be 8 (or less if an enemy dies to a car blowing; that also does not count towards personal kills) even if the sectoid makes a zombie, unless the zombie gets directly killed. I have got 9 kills numerous times (e.g. 3+3+2+1 for the 4 soldiers) when I have killed the zombie before the sectoid.